# Testing API with heavy Load

Tags: java

Currently we want to test our API by sending the concurrent request so we can evaluate the performance, so my code:

```
        int concurrency =2000;
        int loopTimes = 10 ;
       
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(concurrency);

        for(int i=0;i<loopTimes;i++){
            CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(concurrency);

            for(int j=0;j<concurrency;j++) {
                executorService.submit(new POST_REQUEST(body,latch));
            }
            latch.await();
            System.out.println("Query Complete : "+i);


        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

My Run class:

```
  @Override
public void run() {
    try {

        URL url = new URL ("api-url:8080");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setDoOutput(true);

            String body = "[
  {
    event_id: 'b5a9e3ab-d796-4de0-8d4b-00e331785340',
   
  }
]"

        try(OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
            byte[] input = jsonInputString.getBytes("utf-8");
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
        }
     
        latch.countDown();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is my implementation correct Because from the API side we are seeing the garbage data also?

Comment: You are telling the server that you are sending JSON and then sending some plain text.  That isn't correct client side behavior.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for not using tools like hey, jmeter, gattling etc..

Comment: Is `POST_REQUEST` a standard class or your own? Is your "Run" class called `Run`? I think there's a disconnect between the two snippets of code.